# Почему INNER JOIN в SQL получило такое название?

Tags: sql

Понятно что слово **INNER** переводится как **ВНУТРЕННИЙ**. Не понятно почему именно внутреннее соединение а не красное соединение или зеленое?

Comment: нарисуйте диаграммы Эйлера-Венна для каждого случая и всё встанет на свои места :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Диаграммы Эйлера-Венна Вам в помощь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: благадарствую добрый человек